# Add CSS styles to the three first rows of a table

Tags: css

Given the following HTML, I want to add some CSS styles ONLY to the first `.gold`, `.silver` and `.bronze` rows, (having in mind some special behaviors I have commented in the code).

```
<table>
  <tbody>

    <!-- 
      IMPORTANT: 
      Notice that here can appear an extra <tr class="my-rank"></tr> 
      (i.e.: if he user is logged in and he/she have a rank)
    -->

    <tr class="gold"></tr>
    <tr class="silver"></tr>
    <tr class="bronze"></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    
    <!-- 
      From this point, these <tr> elements are injected with AJAX (by a pager), 
      and the three first of ones, includes .gold, .silver and .bronze classes again.
    
      I can't remove these "repeated" classes.
    -->

    <tr class="gold"></tr>
    <tr class="silver"></tr>
    <tr class="bronze"></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>

    <!-- 
      Here is another AJAX injection block, including again undesired .gold, .silver and .bronze classes...
    -->

    <tr class="gold"></tr>
    <tr class="silver"></tr>
    <tr class="bronze"></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    ...
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried several times with pseudo-selectors like `':first-of-type'`, `:first-child`, etc; (also combined with `:not`), with no luck.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after posting this question, I found a solution (although it might not be the more elegant of the solutions):

Finally, I went with these CSS selectors:

```
tr.gold:nth-child(1),
tr.gold:nth-child(2) {
  /* my custom styles  */
}

tr.silver:nth-child(2),
tr.silver:nth-child(3) {
  /* my custom styles  */
}

tr.bronze:nth-child(3),
tr.bronze:nth-child(4) {
  /* my custom styles  */
}
```